# LEFT JOIN con PHP PDO y MVC

Tags: php, ajax, mvc, pdo

tengo la siguiente duda de cómo hacer un LEFT JOIN usando PHP PDO y MVC lo tengo organizado de la siguiente manera:

Este es mi controlador aqui no tengo nada complicado solo envió la variable al modelo :

```
   static public function ctrMostrarProductos($sucursal){

       $respuesta = ModeloProductos::mdlMostrarProductosConRangos($sucursal);

       return $respuesta;

   }
```

Nota: la variable $sucursal la estoy trayendo de un ajax es un ID .

Este es mi Modelo aquí es donde empiezo a tener dudas si esta es la forma en la que se debería hacer la consulta :

```
   static public function mdlMostrarProductosConRangos($sucursal){
       
       $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT *
       FROM productos_sucursales
       LEFT JOIN catalogo ON productos_sucursales.codigo = catalogo.codigo  where productos_sucursales.idSucursal=:sucursal AND productos_sucursales.idEstado='1'
       ORDER BY productos_sucursales.codigo");

       $stmt -> execute([":sucursal" => $sucursal]);

       return $stmt -> fetchAll();


       $stmt -> close();

       $stmt = null;

   }
```

En mi modelo no se si tenga que meter el  `$stmt` en un while para creear un array con las variables o lo puedo mandar directo como lo estoy intentando

Aqui tengo mi ajax que es el que organiza los datos que debería recibir de MODELO

```
<?php
//ini_set('display_errors', '1');   ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');     error_reporting(E_ALL);
session_start();
require_once "../Modelos/productos.modelo.php";
require_once '../Controladores/productos.controlador.php';
class TablaProductos{
     public function mostarTablaProductos(){

        $sucursal=$_POST["sucursal"];

        $productos = ControladorProductos::ctrMostrarProductos($sucursal);

        //var_dump($productos);
        
        
        $datosJason = '{
            "data": [';

            for($i=0; $i<count($productos); $i++){
                
                
                $Botones = "<div class='btn-group'><button class='btn btn-primary AgregarProducto RecuperarBoton' idProducto='".$productos[$i]["id"]."'>Precio Base</button></div>";
                //$Botones01 = "<div class='btn-group'><button class='btn btn-primary AgregarProducto01 RecuperarBoton01' idProducto='".$productos[$i]["id"]."'>Precio Minimo</button></div><br>";
                $BotonBuscar = "<a class='btn btn-warning' href='otras_sucursales.php?idProductoDestino=". $productos[$i]["id"] ."&sucursal=". $productos[$i]["sucursal"] ."&codigo=". $productos[$i]["codigo"] ."'><i class='fas fa-search'></i></a>";
                $BotonAnticipos = "<a class='btn btn-warning' href='Anticipos.php?idProductoDestino=". $productos[$i]["id"] ."&sucursal=". $productos[$i]["sucursal"] ."&codigo=". $productos[$i]["codigo"] ."'><i class='fas fa-box'></i></a>";
                
                $datosJason.= '[
                    "'.$productos[$i]["codigo"].'",
                    "'.$productos[$i]["producto"].'",
                    "'.$productos[$i]["existencia_sucursal"].'",
                    "'.$productos[$i]["precio_sucursal"].'",
                    "'.$productos[$i]["precio_minimo"].'",
                    "'.$Botones.''.$BotonBuscar.''.$BotonAnticipos.'"
                ],';


            }

            $datosJason = substr($datosJason,0,-1);
            $datosJason.= ']}';

        echo $datosJason;

     }
}

$activarproductos = new TablaProductos();
$activarproductos -> mostarTablaProductos();
```

Comment: que tiene que ver el join con tu problema?

Comment: @gbianchi no estoy seguro si es la forma correcta de hacer la consulta ya que no me arroja datos

Comment: y probaste esa consulta en tu db para ver si trae datos?

Comment: @gbianchi si la consulta está bien , no hay problemas con eso , solo que no se si $stmt -> fetchAll(); este retornando algo , debido a que me falte algo en el modelo

Comment: Descomenta esto: `//ini_set('display_errors', '1');   ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');     error_reporting(E_ALL);`, guarda, prueba de nuevo y dinos qué errores ves. **Y si revisas el log de errores MEJOR AÚN**. La gente pierde horas y horas a veces con un problema simple, todo por **no saber depurar**.  Revisando el log de errores, puede ser el problema más endiablado, lo vas a encontrar en menos de 5 minutos, sin el log de errores, te puedes pasar 5 días o soltar el programa en banda con la consiguiente frustración que ello conlleva.